# How to input into a webpage

Tags: python, web, input

I want to put input into a web page say for example auto-login to a website so the python program would open the web page and input the user and password automatically into the web page and press the login button automatically.
how would that be possible.

I want to make a program which I can automatically login into a web page.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://m.facebook.com/login/?locale2=en_GB')
```

- I have the basics of opening this page but now i want to do an input.

The program would open the page and then input email and password then press the login button automatically.

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

If you use `selenium` the following code would do the trick:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep 

usr=input('Enter Email Id:')  
pwd=input('Enter Password:')  

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/') 
print ("Opened facebook") 
sleep(1) 

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email') 
username_box.send_keys(usr) 
print ("Email Id entered") 
sleep(1) 

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass') 
password_box.send_keys(pwd) 
print ("Password entered") 

login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton') 
login_box.click()
print ("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

try selenium webdriver to make login automation.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import time

current_dir=os.getcwd()
#download latest chromedriver according to you OS
driver = webdriver.Chrome(current_dir+'/chromedriver')
url="website url"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)    
email=driver.find_element_by_id('find_input_by_its_id')
email.clear()
email.send_keys("rajat4665@gmail.com")    password=driver.find_element_by_id("pwd-field-id")
password.clear()
password.send_keys('qwerty' + '\n')
time.sleep(1)
#it will login automatically
```